# making sure a given docker container is running

Tags: docker

I'm using docker on quite a lot of servers right now but sometimes some of the containers I use crash due to heavy load. I was thinking on adding a cron that checks every minute of the container is running or not but I didn't find any satisfactory method on doing that.

I'm starting the container with a cidfile that saves the id of the running container. If the container crashes the cidfile stays there with the id inside and I was just wondering how do you guys make sure a container is running or not and respawn it in case it went down. Should I  just parse the output of `docker ps -a` or is there more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you know if it is the container that is crashing or is the command launched inside it which crashes? If it is the process, you can try starting it through supervisord so it is restarted

Comment: The process inside is started with supervisord but I'm fairly sure it's the container crashing since I have to restart the whole docker daemon process on the host in order to be able to start the container again...

Comment: Ugh! That looks like a Docker bug then. I'd make sure that you run the latest docker daemon version and open an issue on the github project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is somewhat buried levels deep but I found out multiple ways of doing it starting with the most elegant:

1. Name your container when running it so you can attach to it's process logging and couple that with a process monitor such as upstart/systemd/supervisord

   `docker run -itd --name=test ubuntu`

   upstart example (`/etc/init/test.conf`):

   `description "My test container"
   start on filesystem and started docker
   stop on runlevel [!2345]
   respawn
   script
       /usr/bin/docker start -a test
   end script`
2. Less elegant: watch for changes in cidfile contents

   `docker run -itd --name=test --cidfile=/tmp/cidfile_path ubuntu`

   An hourly cron maybe...

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   RUNNING=$(docker ps -a --no-trunc | awk '/test/ && /Up/' | awk '{print $1}')
   CIDFILE=$(cat /tmp/cidfile_path)

   if [ "$RUNNING" != "$CIDFILE" ]
   then
      # do something wise
   fi
   ```
3. Similar to the above you can see if a given container is running...in a loop/cron/whatever

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   RUNNING=$(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Running}}' test)

   if [ "$RUNNING" == false ]
   then
      # do something wise
   fi
   ```

You can combine commands to do whatever checking script you like, I went with `upstart` because it suits my situation but these examples could be used for all possible scenarios should you need more control.

Answer (score 4):

Since docker version 1.2.0 there's a new switch for the `run` command called `--restart` which should make any external tools or monitoring obsolete. Since the documentation isn't properly explaining the feature at the time of this writing, read the [announcing blog post](https://blog.docker.com/2014/08/announcing-docker-1-2-0/) for details.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#restart-policies) now got updated as well.