# How to ensure a Docker container starts and stays running on a production server?

Tags: docker, production-environment, supervisord

I'd like to write a Bash script that one would run on a production server. It would download a Docker image from the Docker hub, start it and keep the resulting container running. Inside the container, I'm using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to keep a server and a database running, and Supervisor restarts any process that dies inside the container.

But what about the container itself — are there any recommendations / best-practices about how to ensure that a container starts after the host machine has been rebooted, and that the container restarts if it crashes somehow? There is a [`--restart` flag](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#restart-policies) that one can give to `docker run`. Therefore, to ensure a container starts and stays running, all that's needed is to add this line to `/etc/rc.local`?

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name=container-name image-name command
```

Right? (And I don't need to use `nohup` or any `&`.) Or is there some problem with this approach that I'm overlooking, or something else that I'm missing?

For example, I don't need to somehow ensure that the docker service itself stays up and running? I can trust that it stays alive?

(Related question, but only about keeping docker running, not starting it on reboot: [making sure a given docker container is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24460717/694469))

My host and container OS: Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

With --restart=always you only need to execute docker run once. Docker service will take care about restart after that. So just execute such command once:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name=container-name image-name command
```

and docker will restart container after container process stops and after reboot.